# convert single letter code to 3 letter code along with the chain numbering

Tags: python, function, dictionary, return, biopython

I have a string having single letter AA code ('GPHMAQGTLI'). I want to convert into its respective 3 letter code and give the numbering in a range (300-309) in the same order.

I have written the following but because of 'return' function it is converting only first letter of string

```
d = {'CYS': 'C', 'ASP': 'D', 'SER': 'S', 'GLN': 'Q', 'LYS': 'K',
    'ILE': 'I', 'PRO': 'P', 'THR': 'T', 'PHE': 'F', 'ASN': 'N', 
     'GLY': 'G', 'HIS': 'H', 'LEU': 'L', 'ARG': 'R', 'TRP': 'W', 
     'ALA': 'A', 'VAL':'V', 'GLU': 'E', 'TYR': 'Y', 'MET': 'M'}

def triple_aa(val, num):
    for key, value in d.items():
         if val == value:
             print(key, num)
     
    
def single_aa(x):
    for i in x:
        #print(i)
        return i
        
        

def chain_no(a,b):
    for i in range(a,b+1,1):
        #print(i)
        return i
        
    
    
A= single_aa('GPHMA')
B= chain_no(250,254)
triple_aa(A,B)
```

expected output is as below but I am getting only 'GLY250'

```
print((triple_aa(A,B)) 
GLY250
PRO251
HIS252
MET253
```

Comment: any special reason why you write 3 functions for it ? I think it is not needed here

Comment: Not exactly I need to write but this is what I tried. Actually the string and the number range are given as command line input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also can be achieved by using zip function, and 'for loop'.

```
d= {'CYS': 'C', 'ASP': 'D', 'SER': 'S', 'GLN': 'Q', 'LYS': 'K',
    'ILE': 'I', 'PRO': 'P', 'THR': 'T', 'PHE': 'F', 'ASN': 'N',
    'GLY': 'G', 'HIS': 'H', 'LEU': 'L', 'ARG': 'R', 'TRP': 'W',
    'ALA': 'A', 'VAL':'V', 'GLU': 'E', 'TYR': 'Y', 'MET': 'M'}



def triple_aa(val, num):
    for key, value in d.items():
         if val == value:
             print(key, num, sep='')


    
A= 'GPHMA'
B= range(250,254)
for A,B in zip(A,B):
    triple_aa(A,B)
```

Output will be:

```
GLY250
PRO251
HIS252
MET253
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you could do. First flip key, value of the dict to search easier, then loop through your letter AA code.

**EDIT**

As function with input arguments as you have it:

```
def triple_aa(seq, dic, rng_start):   
    d_flip = {v:k for k,v in dic.items()}
    res = []
    for idx, char in enumerate(seq, rng_start):
        tmp = f"{d_flip.get(char, 'XXX')}{idx}"
        #print(tmp)
        res.append(tmp)
    return res

res = triple_aa('GPHMAQGTLI', d, 300)
print(res)
```

without function:

```
d = {'CYS': 'C', 'ASP': 'D', 'SER': 'S', 'GLN': 'Q', 'LYS': 'K',
    'ILE': 'I', 'PRO': 'P', 'THR': 'T', 'PHE': 'F', 'ASN': 'N', 
     'GLY': 'G', 'HIS': 'H', 'LEU': 'L', 'ARG': 'R', 'TRP': 'W', 
     'ALA': 'A', 'VAL':'V', 'GLU': 'E', 'TYR': 'Y', 'MET': 'M'}
d_flip = {v:k for k,v in d.items()}

s = 'GPHMAQGTLI'

#res = [] # res if you want to access the combinations later
for idx, char in enumerate(s, 300):
    tmp = f"{d_flip.get(char, 'XXX')}{idx}" #if key can't be found 'XXX' as default value
    print(tmp)
    #res.append(tmp)
    
#print(res)

GLY300
PRO301
HIS302
MET303
ALA304
GLN305
GLY306
THR307
LEU308
ILE309
```

Let me know if that works for you